# Which Gini is more reliable, CIA or World Bank?

Tags: development-economics

I would like to ask you a super-basic question.

I need to use Gini coefficient as moderator to examine well-being, resilience and other variables in Immigrants.

Which Gini index is more reliable or popular to use among professional economists, World Bank's or CIA's? Either way, the most recent year are varied depending on countries. How do you deal with it?

Thank you for your advice!